# Pausing execution of calling script when fancybox is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have implemented some form processing using jquery and in some circumstances more information is needed in which case I open a new page in fancybox as shown:

```
moreInfoNeeded = checkInfoComplete();
if (moreInfoNeeded) {
    $.fancybox.open({
        href    : 'iframe.html',
        type    : iframe,
        padding : 5
    });

    // We need to pause execution here until fancybox is closed.
}

// Once fancybox has been closed we have all the information so can continue.
$.ajax({
    ...

    success: function(data)
    {
        window.location.replace(data);
    }
});
```

How do I suspend the execution of the script whilst the fancybox window is open?  At the moment the code above starts to open the fancybox window with the iframe in it but the redirect using `window.location.replace` occurs and closes the fancybox window in the process.

Thanks,

Andy.

Comment: you could use a deferred object and resolve it once fancybox is closed or if no fancybox needed. Or you could use a custom event triggered once needed.

Comment: If the script you want to pause is using ajax then I suspect it has to be synchronous (`async: false`)